# JRE crashes when running sqlite statements

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

I've never seen something like this. I've spent over an hour whittling this down to the simplest I could get it.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.sql.*;

public class Test {
    private static final String DB_PATH = "test.db";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        new File(DB_PATH).delete();

        Connection conn = null;
        Statement s = null;
        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + DB_PATH);

            s = conn.createStatement();
            s.execute("CREATE TABLE person (id integer primary key, name text)");
            s.execute("CREATE VIEW person_view AS SELECT p.id, p.name FROM person p");
            s.execute(""
                + "CREATE TRIGGER person_view_delete INSTEAD OF DELETE ON person_view "
                + "BEGIN delete from person where id = old.id; END"
            );
            s.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO person (id, name) VALUES (42, 'hi')");

            System.out.println("After this line...");
            s.executeUpdate("DELETE FROM person_view WHERE id = 42");
            System.out.println("And before this line...");
        } finally {
            try {
                if (s != null) s.close();
            } finally {
                if (conn != null) conn.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This crashes every single time. The log file:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x76f09b69, pid=3148, tid=5752
#
# JRE version: 7.0_15-b03
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (23.7-b01 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [msvcrt.dll+0x9b69]  memcpy+0x259
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x0076a800):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=5752, stack(0x00d70000,0x00dc0000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x00000000

Registers:
EAX=0x00000002, EBX=0x00000054, ECX=0x00000000, EDX=0x00000002
ESP=0x00dbefb0, EBP=0x00dbefb8, ESI=0x00000000, EDI=0x00dbf2a0
EIP=0x76f09b69, EFLAGS=0x00010293

Top of Stack: (sp=0x00dbefb0)
0x00dbefb0:   00dbf280 00000002 00dbefe8 6c2c6d44
0x00dbefc0:   00dbf2a0 00000000 00000002 6c2e5daa
0x00dbefd0:   00000094 0523dcd0 00dbf108 00000054
0x00dbefe0:   00000000 0523cd00 00dbf258 6c2c6b44
0x00dbeff0:   00dbf280 00000000 00000002 6c2c6d44
0x00dbf000:   00dbf2f7 6c317342 00000001 00000000
0x00dbf010:   00000005 00000000 00000005 00000000
0x00dbf020:   00000007 6c317342 00dbf298 6c2c5bae 

Instructions: (pc=0x76f09b69)
0x76f09b49:   03 88 47 03 8a 46 02 88 47 02 8a 46 01 88 47 01
0x76f09b59:   8b 45 08 5e 5f c9 c3 f3 a5 ff 24 95 b8 99 f0 76
0x76f09b69:   8a 06 88 07 8a 46 01 88 47 01 8b 45 08 5e 5f c9
0x76f09b79:   c3 83 3d 44 00 fa 76 00 0f 84 b5 fd ff ff 57 56 


Register to memory mapping:

EAX=0x00000002 is an unknown value
EBX=0x00000054 is an unknown value
ECX=0x00000000 is an unknown value
EDX=0x00000002 is an unknown value
ESP=0x00dbefb0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0076a800
EBP=0x00dbefb8 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0076a800
ESI=0x00000000 is an unknown value
EDI=0x00dbf2a0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0076a800


Stack: [0x00d70000,0x00dc0000],  sp=0x00dbefb0,  free space=315k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [msvcrt.dll+0x9b69]  memcpy+0x259
C  [libsqlitejdbc-6544525787688936286.lib+0x6d44]  Java_org_sqlite_NativeDB_column_1metadata+0x46ac
C  [libsqlitejdbc-6544525787688936286.lib+0x6b44]  Java_org_sqlite_NativeDB_column_1metadata+0x44ac
C  [libsqlitejdbc-6544525787688936286.lib+0x6e5d]  Java_org_sqlite_NativeDB_column_1metadata+0x47c5
C  [libsqlitejdbc-6544525787688936286.lib+0x6ea5]  Java_org_sqlite_NativeDB_column_1metadata+0x480d
C  [libsqlitejdbc-6544525787688936286.lib+0x37a21]  Java_org_sqlite_NativeDB_column_1metadata+0x35389
C  [libsqlitejdbc-6544525787688936286.lib+0x39b3e]  Java_org_sqlite_NativeDB_column_1metadata+0x374a6
C  [libsqlitejdbc-6544525787688936286.lib+0x228ab]  Java_org_sqlite_NativeDB_column_1metadata+0x20213
C  [libsqlitejdbc-6544525787688936286.lib+0x3a05f]  Java_org_sqlite_NativeDB_column_1metadata+0x379c7
C  [libsqlitejdbc-6544525787688936286.lib+0x3a138]  Java_org_sqlite_NativeDB_column_1metadata+0x37aa0
C  [libsqlitejdbc-6544525787688936286.lib+0x3a506]  Java_org_sqlite_NativeDB_column_1metadata+0x37e6e
C  [libsqlitejdbc-6544525787688936286.lib+0x2e694]  Java_org_sqlite_NativeDB_column_1metadata+0x2bffc
C  [libsqlitejdbc-6544525787688936286.lib+0x2e924]  Java_org_sqlite_NativeDB_column_1metadata+0x2c28c
C  [libsqlitejdbc-6544525787688936286.lib+0x4331b]  Java_org_sqlite_NativeDB_column_1metadata+0x40c83
C  [libsqlitejdbc-6544525787688936286.lib+0x446c3]  Java_org_sqlite_NativeDB_column_1metadata+0x4202b
C  [libsqlitejdbc-6544525787688936286.lib+0x45200]  Java_org_sqlite_NativeDB_column_1metadata+0x42b68
C  [libsqlitejdbc-6544525787688936286.lib+0x35e54]  Java_org_sqlite_NativeDB_column_1metadata+0x337bc
C  [libsqlitejdbc-6544525787688936286.lib+0x3613d]  Java_org_sqlite_NativeDB_column_1metadata+0x33aa5
C  [libsqlitejdbc-6544525787688936286.lib+0x36219]  Java_org_sqlite_NativeDB_column_1metadata+0x33b81
C  [libsqlitejdbc-6544525787688936286.lib+0x1b1e]  Java_org_sqlite_NativeDB_prepare+0x3c
j  org.sqlite.NativeDB.prepare(Ljava/lang/String;)J+0
j  org.sqlite.DB.prepare(Lorg/sqlite/Stmt;)V+21
j  org.sqlite.Stmt.executeUpdate(Ljava/lang/String;)I+16
j  Test.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+83
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [jvm.dll+0x12a34a]
V  [jvm.dll+0x1d968e]
V  [jvm.dll+0x12a3cd]
V  [jvm.dll+0xaede4]
V  [jvm.dll+0xb9157]
C  [javaw.exe+0x206c]
C  [javaw.exe+0xa5a1]
C  [javaw.exe+0xa62b]
C  [kernel32.dll+0x133aa]  BaseThreadInitThunk+0x12
C  [ntdll.dll+0x39ef2]  RtlInitializeExceptionChain+0x63
C  [ntdll.dll+0x39ec5]  RtlInitializeExceptionChain+0x36

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  org.sqlite.NativeDB.prepare(Ljava/lang/String;)J+0
j  org.sqlite.DB.prepare(Lorg/sqlite/Stmt;)V+21
j  org.sqlite.Stmt.executeUpdate(Ljava/lang/String;)I+16
j  Test.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+83
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x00e8e800 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5104, stack(0x04a30000,0x04a80000)]
  0x00e80c00 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5128, stack(0x04450000,0x044a0000)]
  0x00e7f800 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6088, stack(0x04930000,0x04980000)]
  0x00e7c800 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4676, stack(0x047b0000,0x04800000)]
  0x00e69c00 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5528, stack(0x04580000,0x045d0000)]
  0x00e65000 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1184, stack(0x044d0000,0x04520000)]
=>0x0076a800 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=5752, stack(0x00d70000,0x00dc0000)]

Other Threads:
  0x00e63400 VMThread [stack: 0x045d0000,0x04620000] [id=1656]
  0x00ea9800 WatcherThread [stack: 0x048a0000,0x048f0000] [id=5976]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
 def new generation   total 4928K, used 1106K [0x23f00000, 0x24450000, 0x29450000)
  eden space 4416K,  25% used [0x23f00000, 0x24014aa8, 0x24350000)
  from space 512K,   0% used [0x24350000, 0x24350000, 0x243d0000)
  to   space 512K,   0% used [0x243d0000, 0x243d0000, 0x24450000)
 tenured generation   total 10944K, used 0K [0x29450000, 0x29f00000, 0x33f00000)
   the space 10944K,   0% used [0x29450000, 0x29450000, 0x29450200, 0x29f00000)
 compacting perm gen  total 12288K, used 580K [0x33f00000, 0x34b00000, 0x37f00000)
   the space 12288K,   4% used [0x33f00000, 0x33f91090, 0x33f91200, 0x34b00000)
    ro space 10240K,  45% used [0x37f00000, 0x38387290, 0x38387400, 0x38900000)
    rw space 12288K,  54% used [0x38900000, 0x38f8ace8, 0x38f8ae00, 0x39500000)

Card table byte_map: [0x00ec0000,0x00f70000] byte_map_base: 0x00da0800

Polling page: 0x004d0000

Code Cache  [0x02450000, 0x024f8000, 0x04450000)
 total_blobs=186 nmethods=38 adapters=84 free_code_cache=32107Kb largest_free_block=32877568

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 0.288 Thread 0x00e80c00   33             sun.security.provider.SHA::implCompress (491 bytes)
Event: 0.290 Thread 0x00e80c00 nmethod 33 0x024f19c8 code [0x024f1b20, 0x024f20ac]
Event: 0.290 Thread 0x00e80c00   34             sun.nio.cs.SingleByte$Encoder::encode (114 bytes)
Event: 0.291 Thread 0x00e80c00 nmethod 34 0x024f2888 code [0x024f29a0, 0x024f2c70]
Event: 0.369 Thread 0x00e80c00   35             java.lang.String::<init> (67 bytes)
Event: 0.369 Thread 0x00e80c00 nmethod 35 0x024f42c8 code [0x024f4400, 0x024f4640]
Event: 0.370 Thread 0x00e80c00   36             java.util.Arrays::copyOfRange (63 bytes)
Event: 0.371 Thread 0x00e80c00 nmethod 36 0x024f4808 code [0x024f4960, 0x024f4cf8]
Event: 0.372 Thread 0x00e80c00   38             java.lang.Integer::reverseBytes (26 bytes)
Event: 0.372 Thread 0x00e80c00 nmethod 38 0x024f5248 code [0x024f5340, 0x024f53d0]

GC Heap History (0 events):
No events

Deoptimization events (0 events):
No events

Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 0.177 Thread 0x0076a800 Threw 0x23f6f700 at C:\jdk7u2_32P\jdk7u15\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1166
Event: 0.181 Thread 0x0076a800 Threw 0x23f714d8 at C:\jdk7u2_32P\jdk7u15\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1166
Event: 0.214 Thread 0x0076a800 Threw 0x23f7a8c8 at C:\jdk7u2_32P\jdk7u15\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1166
Event: 0.216 Thread 0x0076a800 Threw 0x23f7f950 at C:\jdk7u2_32P\jdk7u15\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1166
Event: 0.217 Thread 0x0076a800 Threw 0x23f85a80 at C:\jdk7u2_32P\jdk7u15\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1166
Event: 0.221 Thread 0x0076a800 Threw 0x23f897e8 at C:\jdk7u2_32P\jdk7u15\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1166
Event: 0.409 Thread 0x0076a800 Threw 0x23ff5c10 at C:\jdk7u2_32P\jdk7u15\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1166
Event: 0.413 Thread 0x0076a800 Threw 0x23ff8c18 at C:\jdk7u2_32P\jdk7u15\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1166
Event: 0.414 Thread 0x0076a800 Threw 0x23ffe960 at C:\jdk7u2_32P\jdk7u15\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1166
Event: 0.420 Thread 0x0076a800 Threw 0x24007ac8 at C:\jdk7u2_32P\jdk7u15\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1166

Events (10 events):
Event: 0.412 loading class 0x04b5af90
Event: 0.413 loading class 0x04b5af90 done
Event: 0.414 loading class 0x04bd0740
Event: 0.414 loading class 0x04bd0740 done
Event: 0.418 loading class 0x04bd0a38
Event: 0.419 loading class 0x04bd0a38 done
Event: 0.420 loading class 0x04bd06c8
Event: 0.420 loading class 0x04bd06c8 done
Event: 0.421 loading class 0x04bc42b8
Event: 0.422 loading class 0x04bc42b8 done


Dynamic libraries:
0x01020000 - 0x0104f000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_15\bin\javaw.exe
0x77920000 - 0x77aa0000     C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll
0x75060000 - 0x75170000     C:\Windows\syswow64\kernel32.dll
0x76990000 - 0x769d7000     C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll
0x751e0000 - 0x75280000     C:\Windows\syswow64\ADVAPI32.dll
0x76f00000 - 0x76fac000     C:\Windows\syswow64\msvcrt.dll
0x76ee0000 - 0x76ef9000     C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll
0x76c10000 - 0x76d00000     C:\Windows\syswow64\RPCRT4.dll
0x75000000 - 0x75060000     C:\Windows\syswow64\SspiCli.dll
0x74ff0000 - 0x74ffc000     C:\Windows\syswow64\CRYPTBASE.dll
0x755a0000 - 0x756a0000     C:\Windows\syswow64\USER32.dll
0x767a0000 - 0x76830000     C:\Windows\syswow64\GDI32.dll
0x76550000 - 0x7655a000     C:\Windows\syswow64\LPK.dll
0x75500000 - 0x7559d000     C:\Windows\syswow64\USP10.dll
0x726c0000 - 0x7285e000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7601.17514_none_41e6975e2bd6f2b2\COMCTL32.dll
0x76fb0000 - 0x77007000     C:\Windows\syswow64\SHLWAPI.dll
0x75170000 - 0x751d0000     C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x75430000 - 0x754fc000     C:\Windows\syswow64\MSCTF.dll
0x676d0000 - 0x6778e000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_15\jre\bin\msvcr100.dll
0x66af0000 - 0x66e3c000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_15\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll
0x6f3e0000 - 0x6f3e7000     C:\Windows\system32\WSOCK32.dll
0x76ba0000 - 0x76bd5000     C:\Windows\syswow64\WS2_32.dll
0x76d20000 - 0x76d26000     C:\Windows\syswow64\NSI.dll
0x729b0000 - 0x729e2000     C:\Windows\system32\WINMM.dll
0x751d0000 - 0x751d5000     C:\Windows\syswow64\PSAPI.DLL
0x67e20000 - 0x67e2c000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_15\jre\bin\verify.dll
0x677e0000 - 0x67800000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_15\jre\bin\java.dll
0x6a040000 - 0x6a053000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_15\jre\bin\zip.dll
0x6ea20000 - 0x6ea36000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTSP.dll
0x6e990000 - 0x6e9cb000     C:\Windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
0x72a00000 - 0x72a17000     C:\Windows\system32\USERENV.dll
0x729f0000 - 0x729fb000     C:\Windows\system32\profapi.dll
0x6a060000 - 0x6a074000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_15\jre\bin\net.dll
0x6e9e0000 - 0x6ea1c000     C:\Windows\system32\mswsock.dll
0x73ea0000 - 0x73ea6000     C:\Windows\System32\wship6.dll
0x71f80000 - 0x71f90000     C:\Windows\system32\NLAapi.dll
0x72600000 - 0x72610000     C:\Windows\system32\napinsp.dll
0x725e0000 - 0x725f2000     C:\Windows\system32\pnrpnsp.dll
0x6d7d0000 - 0x6d814000     C:\Windows\system32\DNSAPI.dll
0x725d0000 - 0x725d8000     C:\Windows\System32\winrnr.dll
0x72060000 - 0x72065000     C:\Windows\System32\wshtcpip.dll
0x728c0000 - 0x728dc000     C:\Windows\system32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
0x728b0000 - 0x728b7000     C:\Windows\system32\WINNSI.DLL
0x741a0000 - 0x741a6000     C:\Windows\system32\rasadhlp.dll
0x6be50000 - 0x6be88000     C:\Windows\System32\fwpuclnt.dll
0x6a030000 - 0x6a03e000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_15\jre\bin\nio.dll
0x6c2c0000 - 0x6c322000     C:\Users\Paul\AppData\Local\Temp\libsqlitejdbc-6544525787688936286.lib
0x72250000 - 0x7233b000     C:\Windows\system32\dbghelp.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252 
java_command: Test
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_15
PATH=C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre7/bin/client;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre7/bin;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre7/lib/i386;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\PharosSystems\Core;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_15\bin;C:\eclipse;
USERNAME=Paul
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 15 Stepping 13, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 7 , 64 bit Build 7601 Service Pack 1

CPU:total 2 (2 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 6 model 15 stepping 13, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, tsc

Memory: 4k page, physical 3143744k(933004k free), swap 6285632k(3672076k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (23.7-b01) for windows-x86 JRE (1.7.0_15-b03), built on Feb 15 2013 14:01:25 by "java_re" with unknown MS VC++:1600

time: Thu Apr 04 05:46:55 2013
elapsed time: 0 seconds
```

I am using sqlitejdbc-v056, and I am developing in Eclipse.

I have exported this as a jar and run it; I have all compiled this to a .class on the command line (outside Eclipse). In neither case was I able to reproduce this.

Curiously, if I define the view as `CREATE VIEW person_view AS SELECT id, name FROM person`, I do not get any error.

My personal congratulations to anyone who can see why this happens. (I am also interested to know if anyone else can reproduce it.)

Comment: Looks like a bug in a native library that is part of the JDBC driver for your database; it crashes in a `memcpy` call because of an illegal pointer access. Check if you can find a different / newer version of the JDBC driver.

Comment: The crash message of the JRE clearly indicates the problem occurs in the sqlite native code. Asking in a forum specific to sqlite/jdbc driver probably has a better chance of getting you an answer.

Comment: Thanks, @Durandal, I probably will go there. But to be honest, I've never seen any forum with better answers than SO.

Comment: @PaulDraper Maybe, couldn't hurt to ask in both places. Doesn't the driver have a website where you can report the problem? I assume the people there have a much better understanding of their own code than anyone here. Although I wouldn't expect a quick response.

Comment: @Jesper, I downloaded a newer driver from https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/downloads. It worked beautifully. I don't know why I didn't think of looking for a newer version. I got this in the framework for a school project.

Answer (score 2):

I'm in two minds as to weather to make this an answer or a comment. This is NOT the answer for the OP but may be very useful for future readers.  Future readers are advised to check they have the latest version as this was what solved the OP's problem.

**Why am I posting if it's not the answer?...**
I've just head a very similar error which could not be distinguished from this one based on the error alone.  I tried with a number of different versions of the xerial sqlite-library and hit the same thing.

After a long time on google and nothing but blanks I eventually discovered this error was being triggered by my code.  I had effectively called:

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + DB_PATH);
s = conn.createStatement();
s.execute(null); // oops
```

This happened because all my queries are packaged up and loaded up separately at runtime, an incorrect reference caused a null pointer where there should have been a query.

In general you expect nothing your code does should crash the JVM.  However where JNI based libraries are concerned this is not always the case.  It seems the xerial sqlite-jdbc library does not do complete null checking and some things (such as a null SQL query) will cause it to crash the JVM on a null pointer.

The null pointer is shown by address "0x00000000" in the error file:

```
siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x00000000
```

However as this was also present in the OP's question it seems that a bug in a previous version would cause this anyway.